# Is there a measure which allows me to tell how closely something is to an ellipse?

Tags: soft-question, circles, applications

[Roundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundness_(object)) is the measure of how closely the shape of an object approaches that of a circle.

I am trying to find a similar measure which shows how closely is something to an ellipse. Is there any similar measure?

Comment: Note that all circles have the same shape. This doesn't happen with ellipses. There are a measure of how much an ellipse differs from a circle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea based on the definition of roundness.

Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$, let $E_{in}$ be the set of ellipses contained in the interior of $C$, and let $E_{out}$ be the set of ellipses contained in the exterior of $C$. Then you can define your 'ellipseness' to be
$$
\sup\left\{\frac{\operatorname{area} (A)}{\operatorname{area}(B)}: A\in E_{in}, B\in E_{out}\right\}.
$$